# Extending Multi-Language Version from Goose in Python

Tags: python, goose

> Goose is a tool which extracts sentences, photos, pictures etc from urls. 
>   This tool is written by python. All codes are in the following URL.

https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/tree/develop/goose

> My main purposes is adding processings for other languages which is NOT  contained at the current version.

First, I read the tutorials, and Chinese and Korean and Arabic languages are able to be applicable by setting "stop_words" parameters.

Thus, I also searched this notion of "stop_words" in the entire packages.
I found the following python-classes.

class StopWords(object):
class StopWordsChinese(StopWords):
class StopWordsArabic(StopWords):
class StopWordsKorean(StopWords):

I also found text files of stop words written in various languages. The place where these files are located is the /resource/text/ in the above URL.

> QUESTION 1:
>   Are there other components in the package to rewrite these codes of Goose and to add the versions of Japanese and all other languages which is NOT included in the newest version??

.

> QUESTION 2:
>    As a firtstep, I wanted to add Japanese procedures. Is there a TIPs for web-scraping from URLs in Japanese??